# Laravel 5.0 Class not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, autoload

I have a class called "Language" on my project im working on which lets you choose a language the page is on and determines which language is currently chosen. I was updating my laravel and ran into a problem on the 5.0 update that it no longer finds my Language class. I think it is an autoloader issue but i am not 100% sure about it.

This is my file order

[image]

Language.php is the class that cant be found and the file that cant find it is home.php under "resources\views\home.php"

This is my Language.php file

```
<?php  
namespace App\Libaries;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Language extends Facade
{
    private static $primary;
    private static $secondary;
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'Language'; }

    public static function init()
    {
        if (strlen(Request::segment(1)) === 2) {
            self::$primary = Request::segment(1);
        } elseif (strlen(Request::segment(1)) !== 2) {
            self::$primary = 'fi';
        }

        if (self::$primary === 'ee' || self::$primary === 'en') {
            self::$secondary = 'fi';
        } elseif (self::$primary !== 'en' && self::$primary !== 'ee') {
            self::$secondary = 'en';
        }
    }

    public static function getsecondary()
    {
        return self::$secondary;
    }

    public static function getprimary()
    {
        return self::$primary;
    }

    public static function getAllLanguages()
    {
        return array(
           'fi' => 'Suomeksi',
           'en' => 'In English',
           'se' => 'På Svenska',
           'de' => 'Deutsch',
           'ru' => 'по-русски',
           'ee' => 'Eesti keeles',
           'pl' => 'Po Polsku',
           'fr' => 'En Français',
           'es' => 'En Español',
           'cn' => '中文',
           'cs' => 'Čeština',
           'sk' => 'Slovenčina',
           'nl' => 'Nederlands',
           'jp' => 'Japanese',
          );
    }

    public static function line($key)
    {
        if (Lang::has($key, self::$primary) === false) {
            return mbUcfirst(Lang::get($key, array(), self::$secondary));
        }
        return mbUcfirst(Lang::get($key, array(), self::$primary));
    }
}

function mbUcfirst($string)
{
    return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1))
         . mb_substr($string, 1);
}
```

This is my home.php file

```
<?php
    namespace App\resources\views;
    use App\Libraries\Language
 ?>

<h1><?=Language::line('common.index')?></h1>
<div id="home-description-text">
    <?=Page::getPage('index')?>
</div>
<div id="home-description">
    <a href="<?=$language?>/project">
        <span id="home-description-title"><?=Language::line('home.description_link_label')?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="home-history">
    <a href="<?=$language?>/history">
        <img id="home-history-image" src="/img/home/history.jpg" alt="history" />
        <span id="home-history-title"><?=Language::line('home.history_link_label')?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="home-map">
    <a href="<?=$language?>/map">
        <img id="home-map-image" src="/img/home/map.jpg" alt="map" />
        <span id="home-map-title"><?=Language::line('home.map_link_label')?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="home-destinations">
    <a href="<?=$language?>/buildings">
        <img id="home-destinations-image" src="/img/home/destinations.jpg" alt="destinations" />
        <span id="home-destinations-title"><?=Language::line('home.destinations_link_label')?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="home-ebook">
    <a href="<?=$language?>/ebook">
        <img id="home-ebook-image" src="/img/home/ebook.jpg" alt="ebook" />
        <span id="home-ebook-title"><?=Language::line('home.ebook_link_label')?></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="clear-both">
</div>
```

This is my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/migrations",
        "database/seeds",
        "app/Http/Controllers",
        "app/Libraries/Language.php",
        "app/models",
        "app/commands",
        "resources/views",
        "resources/lang",
        "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Contracts/View"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "vv5/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Sorry in advance if the formatting is bad this is my first time posting to stack overflow.

I am still new to namespaces so im sure there might be an obvious thing im missing but i cant seem to figure it out on my own. Hopefully this post will help, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the error ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ce6ea1177839253a0ddb8a6a1ebc931b

Comment: may be spelling issue , "namespace App\Libaries" is different from folder name which is "Libraries"

Comment: ahh good catch, i fixed that but sadly the error still remains the same

Comment: I would start with replacing your autoloading rules with rules from original app template:  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/composer.json#L14-L26 and run `composer du`.